# JdbcTemplate to batchUpdate to multiple tables at same time

Tags: spring-jdbc

`JdbcTemplete.batchUpdate()` can take a prepared statement and can fire off a number of inserts to the same table.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1, COL2) VALUES (?, ?)"
List params = ...
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql,  new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
        List<String> singleRowParams = params.get(i);
            ps.setString(1, singleRowParams.get(0));
            ps.setString(2, singleRowParams.get(1));
        }

        // This is the number of times to run the SQL statement. 
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return params.size();
        }
   }
);
```

How do I insert into mutliple tables in the one batch update, is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible. Think about if you were trying to run this SQL manually, how would you go about doing it? An alternative would be to iterate over your updates and amend the SQL each time for the relevant table(s).